# Is there more to enumerate() than just zip(range(len()))?

Tags: python, string, list, enumerate

Everything in Python is there for a reason. All systems powered by Python depend on something like 50 built-in functions, most of which are extremely useful *and unique*, like `format()`, `len()`, `list()`, or `range()`. **I can't understand why `enumerate()` exists**.

It's been introduced in [PEP 279](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/) (2002) and was kept until now. I really don't understand why it exists because it can be done using other more important built-in functions in 2-3 characters more. From the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
```

```
for i in enumerate(seasons):
    print(i)
```

An implementation using more important built-in functions is this:

```
for i in zip(range(len(seasons)), seasons):
    print(i)
```

```
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
```

These two are the same, and we all know how critically important `zip()` and `range()` are. So why add a built-in function that would seemingly add no value beyond these two?

In the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), here is the equivalent of `enumerate()`:

```
def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```

**The bottom line**: I'm wondering if `enumerate()` has some unique capabilities that I'm not seeing.

Comment: I'd think that the difference in readability between the `enumerate` and the equivalent `zip(range(len...` mess is self-evident.  :)  Why have list comprehensions when you can technically use a `for` loop?  Why have `for` when you could technically use a `while`?  Etc.  It's all about making it possible to express common use cases elegantly without requiring a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: Also in your alternative approach, you are repeating `seasons`, which is not a good thing to do in general. So `enumerate` is still better.

Comment: on a one-liner, there might be a little more cluttering, but it's minimal on a for loop, I was just using the official Python example. and to answer your question about the for loop, i actually never use while loops

Comment: Why the entire `itertools` module, when it’s all just recipes you can build using more primitive things…?

Comment: why does Python even exist when you could just code everything in Malbolge?

Comment: itertools is a built-in *library*, there's the difference. i'm pretty sure you're aware of the massive distinction

Comment: Ultimately, the rationale in the PEP really answers this question… https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/#rationale

Comment: how is yours more flexible? what about enumerate is inflexible?

Comment: what makes your approach "flexible"

Comment: You can `enumerate` over a generator, but it does not have `len`; the operation appears similar, but it's not identical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because not every iterable has a length.

```
>>> def countdown(x):
...     while x >= 0:
...         yield x
...         x -= 1
...         
>>> down = countdown(3)
>>> len(down)
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
>>> enum = enumerate(down)
>>> next(enum)
(0, 3)
>>> next(enum)
(1, 2)
```

This is a trivial example, of course. But I could think of lots of real world objects where you can't reasonably pre-compute a length. Either because the length is infinite (see [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)) or because the object you are iterating over does itself not know when the party is over.

Your iterator could be fetching chunks of data from a remote database of unknown size or to which the connection might get lost without warning. Or it could process user input.

```
def get_user_input():
     while True:
        i = input('input value or Q to quit: ')
        if i == 'Q':
            break
        yield i
```

You cannot get the length of `get_user_input()`, but you can `enumerate` all inputs as you fetch them via `next` (or iteration).

Answer (score 4):

The biggest issue I see is an `Iterable` is not necessarily finite. `len` does not make sense for every structure:

```
def infinite():
    n = 0
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 1

for i, n in enumerate(infinite()):
    print(i, n)
```

It would not be possible to use your implementation to enumerate `infinite`.

If you used `infinite` (or `itertools.count`) as a substitute for `range`, it would work:

```
for i, n in zip(infinite(), seasons):
    print(i, n)
```

But, unlike languages like Clojure, [`range`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/range) cannot be infinite unfortunately. You must specify the end, which requires knowing the length ahead of time, which complicates things here.

Answer (score 3):

I feel using [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) would be more appropriate here as an alternative to `enumerate` as `enumerate` doesn't need to know the length it only supplies next number and next object in it's iterations.

```
from itertools import count
for i, o in zip(count(), iterable):
    ...
```

**V.S**

```
for i, o in enumerate(iterable):
    ...
```

Besides, using `len` is adding another unnecessary operation. Although the inclusion of enumerate eliminates the need to import from a library for such simple needs.

Comment: I feel this has the answer within it: why should you need to import a module for something so common…